# Why is my WindowsService taking 20 seconds before the process is terminated?

Tags: windows-services

I have a windows service implemented but have an issue when installing new versions because it seems the old versions process when it is stopped is not terminated immediately and prevents the installer from installing the new version because the .exe cannot be replaced until Windows Task Manager terminated the service process.

Is there something I can do to get Task Manager to immediately terminate the process when the service returns from the OnStop() call?